# Running grunt serve always needs --force option to work

Tags: gruntjs

C:\MyApp>grunt serve
Running "serve" task

Running "clean:server" (clean) task

Running "wiredep:app" (wiredep) task
Warning: ENOENT, no such file or directory 'C:\MyApp\app\bower.json' Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.

Execution Time (2015-01-31 16:27:53 UTC)
wiredep:app  235ms  ■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■ 100%
Total 235ms

Its not true that in path app\bower.json is not a bower.json

There is a bower.json!

**UPDATE**

```
// Automatically inject Bower components into the app
    wiredep: {
      options: {
        cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>'
      },
      app: {
        src: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html'],
        ignorePath:  /\.\.\//
      }
    },
```

Comment: Can you share your wiredep task's code. Also do have a look at https://github.com/stephenplusplus/grunt-wiredep/issues/100

Comment: @PrayagVerma I have updated my question with the wiredep code!

Comment: Yes I use grunt-wiredep 1.9 and when I remove the cwd key in the options the 'grunt serve' works without using '--force' but what did I break now by removing the cwd key?